# Can't install local plugin (zip) with wp-cli

Tags: plugins, wp-cli, docker

I'm using WP-CLI with Docker, everything works fine but I can't seem to find a way to install plugins that are on my local drive.

I'm following the [instructions](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/install/), and do :

```
wp plugin install ../assets/plugins/myplugin.zip
```

I'm expecting WP-CLI to install the plugin, instead I get a :

```
Warning: Couldn't find '/assets/plugins/myplugin.zip' in the WordPress.org plugin directory.
Error: No plugins installed.
```

It seems WP-CLI is treating my zip path as a plugin slug from the plugin directory.

I tried quotes, absolute path, running as root, all with the same result.

Comment: Are you sure the zip is in a folder mapped into the container? If you map a folder into docker, you can't break out of that folder into the host filesystem with `..`, especially if `assets` is in the root folder. Try using an absolute path

Comment: Duh, you're right ! I wasn't mapping the correct asset folder. Thanks.